# Why does this work as a for loop but not within a function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function that identifies if a number within a numerical vector is odd or even. The numerical vector has a length of 1000.

I know that the for loop works fine, and I just wanted to generalize it in the form of a function that takes a vector of any length

```
out<-vector()
f3<- function(arg){
  for(i in 1:length(arg)){
    if((arg[i]%%2==0)==TRUE){
      out[i]<-1
    }else{out[i]<-0
    }
  }
}
```

When run within a function, however, it just returns a NULL. Why is that, or what do I need to do to generalize the function work with any numerical vector?

Comment: You are not returning anything, a function has to return something.

Comment: You can run `your_vector%%2` and you get a vector of the same length that has a 1 for odd and a 0 for even. For instance: 'c(1,2,3,4)%%2' gives `1 0 1 0 `

Comment: Never compare to `TRUE`, if the value already is `TRUE` then by itself it will evaluate to, well, `TRUE`. Your condition is equivalent to `if(arg[i]%%2==0)`.

Comment: Alternatively, use `if(isTRUE(arg[i]%%2==0))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by PKumar in the comments: Your function doesn't return anything, which means, the vector `out` exists only in the environment of your function.

To change this you can add `return(out)` to the end of your function. And you should also start your function with creating `out` before the loop. So your function would look like outlined below.

Note, that I assume you want to pass a vector of a certain length to your function, and get as a result a vector of the same length which contains `1` for even numbers and `0` for odd numbers. `f3(c(1,1,2))` would return `0 0 1`.

```
f3 <- function(arg){

  out <- vector(length = length(arg), mode = "integer")

  for(i in 1:length(arg)){

    if((arg[i]%%2==0)==TRUE){ # note that arg[i]%%2==0 will suffice
      out[i]<-1
    } else {out[i]<-0
    }
  }

  return(out) # calling out without return is enough and more inline with the tidyverse style guide
}
```

However, as also pointed out by sebastiann in the comments, `some_vector %% 2` yields almost the same result. The difference is, that odd numbers yield `1` and even numbers `0`. You can also put this into a function and subtract 1 from arg to reverse `0` and `1` :

```
f3 <- function(arg){
  (arg-1) %% 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few thing to note about your code:

1. A function must return something
2. The logical if((arg[i]%%2==0)==TRUE) is redundant. if(arg[i]%%2==0) is enough, but wrong, because arg[i] does not exist.
3. the length(arg) is the length(1000) which, if ran, returns 1
   You should change arg[i] with i and assign to i all the values from 1:1000, as follows:

R

```
out <-vector()
f3 <- function(arg){
  for(i in 1:arg){
    if(arg[i] %% 2 == 0){
      out[i] <- 1
      }
    else{
      out[i] <- 0
    }
  }
  return(out)
}
f3(1000)
```